# How can I find all words in a string which have a capital letter?

Tags: string, haskell, char

`a` is a string and I would like to find all words in the string which have an upper case character.

How can I convert the string to chars?

```
listWordsWithUpper :: String -> [String]
listWordsWithUpper a = filter (any . (isUpper a))
```

Example:

```
listWordsWithUpper "Haskell is tHe BEST" == ["Haskell", "tHe", "BEST"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Haskell, a string is a list of characters. I mean that literally. The type `String` is an *alias* to `[Char]`. So a string is already a list of characters.

The piece you're missing is the tokenization part. You've got a big string and you want to split it at each word boundary. There are more complicated tokenization functions for general solutions, but for this particular case, the built-in function [`words`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words) will do just fine.

```
words :: String -> [String]
```

So we want to take a string, tokenize it, and then apply a filter so as to keep only the things which contain uppercase characters. For the second half, your `filter` is close. We want to filter and keep any strings where `any isUpper myString` is true. So something like this will work.

```
listWordsWithUpper :: String -> [String]
listWordsWithUpper = filter (any isUpper) . words
```